# Class in mainfile, method in another file

Tags: python, class, import

I have two files, in the mainfile I have a class, in the other file I have a method which uses/edits the object of the class, how can I import the file.

mainfile:

```
import..? # the other file


class Fields:
        def __init__(self, y , x):
            self.positionx=x
            self.positiony=y
            self.color = 'white'
            self.free = True

            self.update()


        def update(self):
            ###



Field1=Fields(1,3)
###
### whatever...
```

2ndfile:

```
def change_color():
    actualcolor=Field1.color
    Field1.color='blue'
    Field1.update()
    ###
```

I tried:
    form 2ndfile import change_color
but it gave me the error:

```
NameError: name 'Field1' is not defined
```

Is it clear? How do I need to do that?

Tkx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is called Circular imports, which is something that is not supported by Python.
You can read more about it [here](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/), in general, it means that it's not possible to have 2 files which are dependent on each other.

To solve that problem, all you have to do is to extract the resource both files need, to another file they can import from, for example:

**models.py**

```
class Fields:
        def __init__(self, y , x):
            self.positionx=x
            self.positiony=y
            self.color = 'white'
            self.free = True

            self.update()


        def update(self):
            ###



Field1=Fields(1,3)
```

**main.py**

```
from models import Field1
from other_file import ...

def main():
    # Do stuff
```

**other_file.py**

```
from models import Field1
def change_color():
    actualcolor=Field1.color
    Field1.color='blue'
    Field1.update()
    ###
```